# How to set label for Hangouts Meeting via API

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

**Background**

I'm trying to create an appointment calendar using GSuite and Google Calendar API. When a user (no Google account and outside the GSuite organization) creates an appointment, I'm trying to create a Calendar event on the Calendar of an organization member via the `Google Calendar API` and generate a Hangouts meeting link.

**Problem**

I can create the event and the Hangouts meeting link, but I cannot create a custom label for the video link. I was able to make it slightly unique by adding an attendee with a fake email `xczczf@example.com` to John Doe's calendar to get a label of `doe-j-xcz`, but I would like full control over the label if possible.

**Attempted Solutions That Didn't Work**

1. Create the event and provide a `conferenceData.createRequest` and an `entryPoint` with the desired label.
2. Create the event first and then send a patch with the information described in 1
3. Changing the `conferenceId`

Answer (score 1):

After messing around with the API Explorer, a custom label can be made by:

1. Creating the Cal event and adding a meeting link using a createRequest
2. Send a Patch with `conferenceData.conferenceId` set to the unique label value